# Is a $compile needed or is my directive wrongly structured?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Reading the documentation I'm not sure if I should be doing a pre-compile of this directive or if my methodology doesn't work. The error i get is an "unexpected token email in emails".

Is it possible that the directive's internal controller hasnt passed the email class to the scope of the directive?

//html

```
<div data-ng-app = "appSubs"> 
  <email-subscription>
  </email-subscription>
</div >
```

//js

```
angular.module('appSubs', [])
    .directive('emailSubscription', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="{{email in emails}}">Name: {{email.name}} </li>' +
                    '</ul>',
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.emails = [{
                name: 'Weekly Newsletter'},{
                    name: 'Monthly Newsletter'}
            ];
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove {{ and }} from email in emails )

Comment: wow quick response, and it works, Merry {{SuitableUnoffensiveGreetingHere}}